# Crystal Reports PrintToPrinter performance degrading over time

Tags: c#, performance, crystal-reports

We have an application that prints small dockets all the time. The dockets are Crystal Reports. We have about 10 different docket designs and layouts.

There is no data access done from CR, we process and pass all the data to the report document as an ArrayList.

We have measured massive lag spikes in the PrintToPrinter function. As you can see in this chart, they seem to increase over time:

[image: Chart showing lag spikes in PrintToPrinter]

The blue lines show the time PrintToPrinter took to complete in seconds. Most of the time it is under 1 second but some times it takes up to 200. Orange lines are points where the application was started.

Interestingly we also tried changing PrintToPrinter with ExportToDisk (PDF) and the spikes seem to happen with a similar pattern.

This is a chart from another machine using ExportToDisk(PDF):
[image: Chart showing lag spikes in ExportToDisk(PDF)]

Some additional information:

- Users report that when lag starts to happen they can "unfreeze and get it to print" by clicking repeatedly on the application surface.
- There are no antivirus programs running on these machines.
- This issue has been impossible to reproduce in non production environments. We only rely on logs, but it seems to happen on different environments (Windows versions, printers, PCs).
- We tried caching the report document objects and it had great results on only a couple of machines but generally it was worse.

Comment: How are you cleaning up after each print? Are you properly disposing of the report document? What version of the Crystal runtime is it? Have you tried the client document API PrintReport method?

Comment: Hi, we are using the developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio SP 12. We call reportDocument1.Close() and reportDocument1.Dispose() after each print.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said here, I would be of the opinion that "the culprit is probably not Crystal Reports."  I think that you are observing some kind of *external* influence, completely unrelated to Crystal (or, quite likely, to any other "piece of software."  I would suggest looking at other types of logs ... system logs.

In considering what might be the root cause of this most-curious problem, my first instinct would be to "not give *too* much credence" to the user's reports that they can get it to un-stick by clicking the mouse.  It *could* be relevant, but it could just as easily be a(mother) red herring.  (When users are trying to get a computer to stop being unresponsive, they either bang on the keyboard or click on the mouse ...)

Obviously, "if something causes a computer to wait for more than two minutes," that something is *probably* some kind of: **timeout**.  Probably somewhere in the printing subsystem.  And it seems to me that the printer subsystem and/or the general system logs of those computers *should* have produced *some* kind of message or event-log that can be matched-up very precisely with the exact times when these problems occur.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought it could be something related to the print spooler but it seems that exporting to PDF shows a similar behaviour and it does not relate to printing.

I have looked at the event logs and there does not seem to be anything directly related to this at least not 1 to 1 exact times.

Comment: Well, "how exactly" does 'export to PDF' *work?*  Maybe it's actually being done by the print-spooler, and maybe (therefore) it's subject to being blocked by the same thing.  Might well be worth looking into.  Also:  your parenthetical comment *"at least not ..."* raises at-least an eyebrow with me.  Given that we all know we're dealing with a *"WTF?!?!"* situation here, *any* sort of "clue" is ... a "clue."

Comment: The ExportToDisk function seems to be an independent function from the printer and it does seem to take less time. I was very surprised it lagged at all as it does seem to rule out the print queue as a factor.

Comment: It is *overwhelmingly suspicious* to me ...as in "we know who did it, we just don't (yet) know where he hid the gun" ... that "ExportToDisk" would take *two minutes(!)* to complete.  Nope ... *"bzzzt, sorry!"* ... that just don't fly.  Therefore, you *must* be chasing a red-herring here.  Dunno what it might be, but:  *"okay, okay, this I-S ... hogwash."*  "Exporting anything-at-all to disk" obviously should take *milliseconds.*  Given that it most-obviously doesn't, it stands to reason that there must be *something* standing in the way, and that IT must be 'the smoking gun.'  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Getting to where we are now has taken me weeks and you got there immediately. I just hope there was a smoking gun detector.

Comment: Oh, hell, I could just as easily be totally-wrong.  I'm only going on my gut.  There's got to be *something* that is causing "a big, timeout-sized, delay."  It can't be anything software, because *even Crystal* (wink, wink ...) isn't (usually, wink...) THAT slow.  :-)  I wonder if it might have something to do with the time-of-day.  (I'm not entirely kidding.  I once had a client whose business was run from a trailer, and his computers would act up every day ... at about lunch-time ... when the employees would usually heat up their stuff on a stove ... a big, POWER-HUNGRY stove in a TRAILER...

Comment: (P.S.  Nope, the trailer didn't burn down.  But you can bet they hired an electrician to re-wire the thing, and they bought UPS-boxes for every piece of computer equipment, putting all of it on dedicated circuits..  And a couple years later, they built a nice new building to be their offices.)